# $E(X)=2$ and $E(X(X−1))=5$. Find $V(X)$?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, variance

$E(X)=2$ and $E(X(X−1))=5$. Find $V(X)$?

I know that $E(X(X−1))= E(X^2-X) = 5$

and that $V(X) = E(X^2)−[E(X)]^2$

But I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you know that $E(X^{2}-X)$ is same as $EX^{2}-EX$? If yo u know that I m sure that you can answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expectation is linear, hence:

$5=E[X^2-X]=E[X^2]-E[X]=E[X^2]-2$

So $E[X^2]=7$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: So then, $V(X) = 7 - 2^2 = 7-4 = 3$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: and $E[X2−X]=E[X2]−E[X]$ can be broken down this way due to linearity?

Comment: Yes. Linearity means that $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ and $E[cX]=cE[X]$ for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$. So in our case $E[X^2-X]=E[X^2+(-1)X]=E[X^2]+E[(-1)X]=E[X^2]+(-1)E[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]$.